# How to mint one token that allows multiple holders?

Tags: smartpy, nft

I'm using the fa2_nft_minimal.py to mint NFTs, but I'd like to mint a single NFT that can have multiple holders.
How do I do that in smartpy?
Like this: https://tzkt.io/KT1RJ6PbjHpwc3M5rw5s2Nbmefwbuwbdxton/tokens/78345/holders

1 token - 10 holders

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already asked nearly the same question here: [Minting several Nfts in one operation](https://tezos.stackexchange.com/questions/4489/minting-several-nfts-in-one-operation)

You are misunderstanding on what you call a NFT. The contract you gave as an example is not technically a NFT contract, it's at best a semi-fungible contract. A NFT, by definition, can only be minted once, the total supply cannot exceed one.

The example contract was using the old `FA2.py` template from SmartPy. The new solution is the FA2_lib.

If you want to do the same thing as hicetnunc you have to use the fungible ledger and entrypoints of the FA2. That's what I explained in my answer https://tezos.stackexchange.com/a/4490/5292. (option B, solution 1).

Comment: Question is about NFT with multiple holders, this is different from fungible tokens.

Actually there is multiple solutions depending on Rafael use case.

Comment: I edited my answer to be cristal clear. There is a misunderstanding on the question by both you and Rafael Viana. Are these edit convicing enough for you to remove the negative vote?

Comment: OK, I removed negative vote

Answer (score 1):

NFT contracts are single owner.

One solution to have multi-owners NFT can be to have its owner an originated address (KT1) which is a multisig.

Comment: Edited, and present it as One solution not The solution

Answer (score 0):

I saw the solution in one of the examples provided in the online editor.
I could mint to multiple holders by restructuring the way the ledger was set.

What I had before was:

```
...
self.init(
    ...
    ledger=sp.big_map(tkey=sp.TNat, tvalue=sp.TAddress),
    ...
...
def mint(self, to_, metadata)
    ...
    self.data.supply[token_id] = amount
    self.data.ledger[token_id] = to_
    self.data.next_token_id += 1
```

instead of a nat, the ledger key can be a tuple.

```
...
self.init(
    ...
    ledger=sp.big_map(tkey=sp.TPair(sp.TAddress, sp.TNat), tvalue=sp.TNat),
    ...
...
def mint(self, to_, amount, metadata):
    ...
    self.data.ledger[(to_, token_id)] = amount
    self.data.next_token_id += 1
```

Comment: That's the code of `fa2_fungible_minimal.py` for fungible tokens. A token type with an amount > 1 is by definition a fungible token. If you want to keep it as an NFT (meaning any token can be distinguished from another) that's not the solution. Otherwise, that's the solution but, again, you should use the fa2 library. PS: I'm wrote the code of the `fa2_nft_minimal.py`, `fa2_fungible_minimal.py` and the `fa2_lib.py`.